# Write a SML function that take the name of a file and return a list of char without spaces

Tags: sml, ml, polyml

In an exam i found this exercise:
"Write a function that take a file name (i.e. "text.txt") and return a list of char without blanks"

#### For example:

"text.txt" contains *"ab e ad c"*
the function must return -> *[#"a",#"b",#"e",#"a",#"d",#"c"]*

**Which is the easiest way to solve the exercise?**

I've tried to use the library "TextIO" and the function "input1" but i got stuck. I don't know how to implement the function recursively. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun chars filename =
  let
    val f = TextIO.openIn filename
    val s = TextIO.inputAll f
  in
    TextIO.closeIn f;
    List.filter (fn c => c <> #" ") (explode s)
  end
```